# Question Regarding Probability of Joint Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

I am facing this problem that i dont quite fully understand.

> The joint density function of X and Y is given by $f(x, y) = xy$ ,  $0 < x < 1, 0 < y < 2
> $ and is equal to $0$ outside the region.

My task is to find $P(X+Y>1)$.

This is my attempt:

$\int_{0}^{2} \int_{1-y}^{1} xy$ $ dxdy$, which i verified to be $\frac{2}{3}$.

However, the solution writes: $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{1-x}^{2} xy$ $ dydx$ = $\frac{23}{24}$.

Is the way i set up the integration wrong? My reasoning is that since $ X + Y > 1$, then $X > 1 - Y $ , which is why i wrote $1-y$ as the lower bound.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you naively calculate $\int_{0}^{2} \int_{1-y}^{1} xy\,dx\,dy$ your $x$-es at one point run from $1-y>1$ down to $1\,.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **intersection** of *the support* and *the event* is:

$$\{(x,y):0<y<2, \max\{0,1-y\}<x<1\}$$

So your integral should have been partioned by $0<y<1$ and $1\leq y<2$:

$$\begin{align}\int_0^2\int\limits_{\max\{0,1-y\}}^1 xy\,\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d y &=\int_0^1\int_{1-y}^1 xy\,\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d y+\int_1^2\int_0^1 xy\,\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d y \\[2ex] &=\dfrac{23}{24}\end{align}$$

On the other hand, $\max\{0,1-x\}$ will always be $1-x$ when $0<x<1$, so no parting is required.

$$\begin{align}\int_0^1\int\limits_{\max\{0,1-x\}}^2 xy\,\mathrm d y\,\mathrm d x &=\int_0^1\int_{1-x}^2 xy\,\mathrm d y\,\mathrm d x\\[2ex] &=\dfrac{23}{24}\end{align}$$